# Getting started with struts2

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, struts2

I'm trying to setup maven and struts 2 project in Eclipse, but I'm having problems. I have chosen to create simple HelloWorld example and afterwards add some other functionality, but I'm having problems.

---

I have 'struts.xml' path in project:  src/main/resources/struts.xml

and inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="Login">
            <result>/Pages/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="Index">
            <result>/Pages/Index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="Welcome" class="com.contactweb.main.Contact">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/Pages/Welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

---

also I have web.xml with path src/main/web/WEB-INF/web.xml and content:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>ContactWeb</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

From commandline I use 'mvn clean install' and I get .war file to target folder, that .war file I'm going to deploy under Tomcat (also it deploys it successfully) but when I enter url I get error:

> The requested resource (/ContactWeb/Pages/Login.jsp) is not available.

same error with different url-s only path is different (/ContactWeb/Login.jsp, /ContactWeb/Login.action etc.).

In my project I do have Login.jsp, Index.jsp and also Welcome.jsp. They are under: src/main/web/Pages

I have read somewhere that in struts2 I need to but .action extension to url, but it doesn't work and also why in struts.xml is package name and namespace? what exactly needs to be there? I have read that  is for page what it is going to display?

Comment: (I appreciate the "accept", but unless it specifically helped, at best it should just be voted up for being helpful--I just couldn't fit all that into a readable comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information to help yet, but enough wrong that it won't fit into a comment.

- Why are you using an ancient servlet spec (2.3? Should be at least 2.5 for a variety of reasons.)
- Why are you using an old version of S2 (2.0? We're on 2.3.)
- The result name for the `Welcome` action should almost certainly be the default, `"success"`, unless you're explicitly not using the S2 result names. Which IMO would be a bad idea.
- We don't know what context you're deploying to, so we don't know the path to your web app. If you're deploying to the `ContactWeb` context, then the `Login` action would be at `/ContactWeb/Login.action` (or whatever your suffix is, if you have one).
- You should (a) turn `devMode` on, and (b) turn up logging to the `DEBUG` level while troubleshooting.
- Do you JSP pages live in the `src/main/webapp/Pages` directory? Note that it's typical to hide JSPs from direct access by putting them under `WEB-INF`--I'd recommend you follow that practice.
- Is there anything in your startup logs that would indicate the app isn't starting up?

I'd recommend reading some of the [S2 Guides](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/guides.html); if you don't know what the "package" and "namespace" attributes signify then IMO you should take a step back and try to understand some of the basics before randomly throwing code and configuration at a web container.